# Unable to bind custom adapter to layouts with include tag

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am trying to use Kotlin's Sealed class for handling states in my app. I have seperated different states in different layout files for reusing them. But the problem is that even though I am able to using it in a fragment successfully it is not working in another fragment. Log is very confusing for this error. Maybe there is a subtle error which I am not able to find in my code.

This is my sealed class which is used for state handling :

```kotlin
sealed class LoadStates {
    object Loading : LoadStates()
    class Error(val msg: String = "Something went wrong") : LoadStates()
    class Empty(val msg: String = "No item") : LoadStates()
    object NotEmpty : LoadStates()

    companion object {
        fun <T> decideEmptyOrNot(list: List<T>?,msg: String): LoadStates {
            return if (list.isNullOrEmpty()) { Empty(msg) } else { NotEmpty }
        }
    }
}
```

There are the custom binding adapter that I am using :

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter("bindLoadingState")
fun uiStateWhileLoading(view: View, state: LoadStates) {
    view.visibility = if (state is LoadStates.Loading) { View.VISIBLE } else { View.GONE }
}

@BindingAdapter("bindErrorState")
fun uiStateWhenError(view: LinearLayout, state: LoadStates) {
    view.visibility = if(state is LoadStates.Error) {
        val msg = view.getChildAt(1) as TextView
        msg.text = state.msg
        View.VISIBLE
    } else { View.GONE }
}

@BindingAdapter("bindEmptyState")
fun uiStateWhenEmpty(view: LinearLayout, state: LoadStates) {
    if(state is LoadStates.Empty) {
        val msg = view.getChildAt(1) as TextView
        msg.text = state.msg
        view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        view.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("bindNonEmptyState")
fun uiStateWhenNotEmpty(view: View, state: LoadStates) {
    view.visibility = if (state is LoadStates.NotEmpty) { View.VISIBLE } else { View.INVISIBLE }
}

@BindingAdapter("bindDisableState")
fun bindButtonDisableState(view: View, state: LoadStates) {
    view.isEnabled = state !is LoadStates.Loading
}
```

XML code of my layout file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="presenter"
            type="bd.edu.daffodilvarsity.classmanager.features.admin.bookedrooms.rangeddate.BookedRoomsRangedDate" />
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="bd.edu.daffodilvarsity.classmanager.features.admin.bookedrooms.common.BookedRoomsAdminViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".features.admin.bookedrooms.rangeddate.BookedRoomsRangedDate">

        ...
        ......
        ............

        <include
            layout="@layout/state_empty"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:state="@{viewModel.uiStates}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_view"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/state_loading"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:bindLoadingState="@{viewModel.uiStates}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_view" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/state_error"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:state="@{viewModel.uiStates}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_view"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:bindNonEmptyState="@{viewModel.uiStates}"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="18dp"
            android:onClick="@{() -> presenter.fetchBookedRooms()}"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            app:bindDisableState="@{viewModel.uiStates}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

XML files of my 3 states :

state_loading : https://pastebin.com/AhwvV69P

state_error : https://pastebin.com/TnfynHNi

state_empty : https://pastebin.com/xLeQQ1GX

I am pretty sure my ui state livedata is not null. Here is the Crash Log :

```
2020-08-10 17:34:14.837 15167-15167/bd.edu.daffodilvarsity.classmanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: bd.edu.daffodilvarsity.classmanager, PID: 15167
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method
        at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$MethodReference.invokeCallback(ClassesInfoCache.java:226)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeMethodsForEvent(ClassesInfoCache.java:194)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeCallbacks(ClassesInfoCache.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.onStateChanged(ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.java:37)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:300)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:339)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:131)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:51)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2737)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:365)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1194)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:915)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter state
        at bd.edu.daffodilvarsity.classmanager.common.adapter.CustomBindingAdaptersKt.uiStateWhileLoading(Unknown Source:7)
        at bd.edu.daffodilvarsity.classmanager.databinding.FragmentBookedRoomsRangedDateBindingImpl.executeBindings(FragmentBookedRoomsRangedDateBindingImpl.java:206)
        at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executeBindingsInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:473)
        at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:445)
        at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding$OnStartListener.onStart(ViewDataBinding.java:1687)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$MethodReference.invokeCallback(ClassesInfoCache.java:216)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeMethodsForEvent(ClassesInfoCache.java:194) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache$CallbackInfo.invokeCallbacks(ClassesInfoCache.java:185) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.onStateChanged(ReflectiveGenericLifecycleObserver.java:37) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:300) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:339) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:131) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(FragmentViewLifecycleOwner.java:51) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2737) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:365) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1194) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:915)
```

Comment: it stated this `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null` means it is getting null value in Non-Null param.
Can you please tell me when you click on the error on which custom adapter it takes to?

Comment: The problem is it doesn't take me to a custom adapter it takes me to the import statement of the custom adapter file where a TextView is imported. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is that you have not passed the value for the LoadState in the following layout binding

```
@BindingAdapter("bindLoadingState")
fun uiStateWhileLoading(view: View, state: LoadStates) {
    view.visibility = if (state is LoadStates.Loading) { View.VISIBLE } else { View.GONE }
}
```

here state is null because you are not binding variable in the **state_loading.xml** layout itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <!--add missing state binding variable here-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ProgressBar
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true" />
 
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/loading_data"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

now I guess you know what to do. just add a binding variable just like you have added in other layout files in the above file.

```
<data>
      <variable
      name="state"  type="bd.edu.daffodilvarsity.classmanager.common.models.LoadStates" />
</data>
```

**Edit**:

Try making your adapter functions parameters nullable which might be null on start.

```
@BindingAdapter("bindLoadingState")
fun uiStateWhileLoading(view: View?, state: LoadStates?) {
    if(view!=null && state!=null)
    view.visibility = if (state is LoadStates.Loading) { View.VISIBLE } else { View.GONE }
}

@BindingAdapter("bindErrorState")
fun uiStateWhenError(view: LinearLayout?, state: LoadStates?) {
    if(view!=null && state!=null)
    view.visibility = if(state is LoadStates.Error) {
        val msg = view.getChildAt(1) as TextView
        msg.text = state.msg
        View.VISIBLE
    } else { View.GONE }
}

@BindingAdapter("bindEmptyState")
fun uiStateWhenEmpty(view: LinearLayout?, state: LoadStates?) {
    if(view!=null && state!=null)
    if(state is LoadStates.Empty) {
        val msg = view.getChildAt(1) as TextView
        msg.text = state.msg
        view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        view.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("bindNonEmptyState")
fun uiStateWhenNotEmpty(view: View?, state: LoadStates?) {
    if(view!=null && state!=null)
    view.visibility = if (state is LoadStates.NotEmpty) { View.VISIBLE } else { View.INVISIBLE }
}

@BindingAdapter("bindDisableState")
fun bindButtonDisableState(view: View?, state: LoadStates?) {
    if(view!=null && state!=null)
    view.isEnabled = state !is LoadStates.Loading
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is the case. I am binding the whole view with a custom binding method so must be okay. Although I am using same code in another fragment without any problem.

Comment: yes you are right since there is binding adapter is getting used in this layout but error is with this bindLoadingState() function only not sure from which layout file, but some file is passing the null for LoadState

Comment: The problem persist even though I remove the layout for loading state. So this means same problem occurs with other custom layouts that I have included too. :(

Comment: but if you make it nullable right, then it won't make an issue, sinece binding adapter might be calling it when there is no values also on starting, in such cases it will be null since it changes as live data values and is called mulitple times, so declaring it nullable will remove the error.

Comment: When I logged the value of `LoadState` after making it nullable I saw that it was null. But when I logged it in the observer inside my fragment everything was okay. The problem with your solution is that my views are not getting notified when state is getting changed. I think I will go mad for this bug.

Comment: My problem is fixed. Thanks for your help.